# Home Assistant: solar production graph not working

Tags: home-assistant

I have today added the FusionSolar integration through HACS so I can monitor my solar panel production in HA. Under Settings > Dashboards > Energy under solar panels I've added the sensor for today's production. However, when I go to the Energy dashboard, I only see the "Energy Distribution" card and the "Solar Production" card is empty. What am I missing here? I double checked the sensor I'm using and it has `state_class: total_increasing` and `device_class: energy` (see below).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my HA Docker version solved the issue for me.